# Is $\ell^1$ an inner product space?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Considering the parallel result for $L^p$ spaces, I would guess that $\ell^1$ is not an inner product space. The proof would presumably follow by providing counterexample sequences $x  = (x_n) $ and $y = (y_n)$ violating the parallelogram law, *i.e.*, satisfying:

$$2\|x\|_1^2+2\|y\|_1^2\neq \|x+y\|_1^2+\|x-y\|_1^2 $$

I can't find a counterexample. Any hints?

Comment: I think you are missing some squares in your parallelogram law.

Comment: Sorry I misseed the squares. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$x = (1,1,0,0, \ldots )$

$y = (1,-1,0,0, \ldots) $

By the way, note that $\ell_1$ is complete and separable but has non-separable dual. On the other hand, Hilbert spaces are isomorhic to their dual spaces. This shows that $\ell_1$ is not linearly isomorphic to an inner-product space.

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply the result for $L^1$ spaces, because $\ell^1 = L^1(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure.

Comment: Yes, but i want to do it with the parallelogram law.

Comment: @Iconoclast, you can apply the parallelogram law in this case too. Let $A, B$ be two disjoint sets of finite measure and define $f = \bigg(\frac{1}{\mu(A)}\bigg)^{1/p} \cdot \chi_A$ and $g = \bigg( \frac{1}{\mu(B)} \bigg)^{1/p} \cdot \chi_B$ and notice that the parallelogram law only works when $p = 2$, so in the case above, $p = 1$, it doesn't work, which implies the result for $\ell^1$.

Comment: I tried to follow your prescription. I have trouble with expanding the second term in $\|f+g\|_1^2+\|f-g\|_1^2$ because of the negative sign with $g$ and the absolute value.